# how is it possible to Initalize a Val inside a loop?

Tags: loops, kotlin, variables, initialization

very very starter here, so not very knewledge. Can anyone explain me why this code in Kotlin below works?

How can I initalize a val inside the loop every iteration??

```
    val n = readln().toInt()
     
    repeat(n) {
            val next = readln().toInt()
            sum += next
        }
```

Comment: Why shouldn't it be a valid code? what is the problem? loops body is like any other place!

Comment: Isn't the loop creating a val with the same name every iteration? isn't val's with the same name invalid? Or is the val gone at the end of the loop because it's the end of its scope

Comment: in Kotlin it is gone at the end of the loop because after the loop, it is outside of the scope and you can not access it. in each iteration of the loop any newly initialized `val` or `var` is available until the end of that iteration.

Answer (score 1):

`next` is not "variable" shared for each loop iterations.

It's declaration in [statement scope](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/scopes-and-identifiers.html) inside loop.

In other words, `next` for first iteration and `next` for second iteration are two independent values.

Answer (score 0):

Variables declared as `val` cannot change their reference, you'll need to use `var` for that:

```
val n = readln().toInt()

var sum = 0
repeat(n) {
    val next = readln().toInt()
    sum += next
}

println(sum)
```

Your code already declares a `val` each iteration. It isn't needed though, you can directly increase `sum`:

```
sum += readln().toInt()
```

Comment: Shorter: `val sum = (1..n).fold(0) { sum, _ -> sum + readln().toInt() }`

Comment: @EmanuelMoecklin you can just do `(1..n).sumBy { readln().toInt() }` if you like! Or `generateSequence { readln().toInt() }.take(n).sum()` if that feels a bit cleaner